# How to solve `(logList: string[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string[], index: number) => ObservableInput<any>`?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem to make an observable object from two observables and keep the order of the first observable. As you can see in the example, the goal is to sort the observables by date.

It looks like the problem lies in the `ngOnInit()` since there I get the error at the line `concatMap(logList => {`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(logList: string[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string[], index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
```

I'm using `concatMap` because otherwise sometimes I have the problem that the `dailyLogs` are not in the right order.

I have already tried and searched a lot, but after more than a day I could not find anything to get rid of this error message. The strange thing is also that even with this error it sometimes compiles and then the result is the right one.

Also using `return` inside the `concatMap` did not work => `return dailyLogs.push({logs: logList, date});`

What am I doing wrong?

Following is my example code:

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dailyLogs$: Observable<{logs: string[], date: Date}[]>;

  constructor(
    private readonly logService: LogService,
    private readonly dateService: DateService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dailyLogs$ = this.dateService.getDates()
      .pipe(
        map(values => {
          const dates = Array<Date>();
          values.forEach(value => {
            if (value) {
              dates.push(value);
            }
          });
          return dates;
        }),
        map(dates => {
          const dailyLogs = Array<{logs: string[], date: Date}>();
          dates.forEach(date => {
            this.logService.findLogsByDate(date)
              .pipe(
                concatMap(logList => {
                  dailyLogs.push({logs: logList, date});
                })
              ).subscribe();
          });
          return dailyLogs;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dailyLogs$">
  <div *ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2]">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Logs</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let log of (dailyLogs$ | async)[i].logs">
        <td>{{log}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**log.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogService {

  firstLogs = [
    'Log 1',
    'Log 2',
    'Log 3',
    'Log 4'
  ];

  secondLogs = [
    'Log 5',
    'Log 6',
    'Log 7',
    'Log 8',
    'Log 9',
    'Log 10',
    'Log 11'
  ];

  thirdLogs = [
    'Log 12',
    'Log 13'
  ];

  findLogsByDate(date: Date): Observable<string[]> {
    const dateString = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);

    if (dateString === '2019-12-17') {
      return of(this.firstLogs);
    } else if (dateString === '2019-12-16') {
      return of(this.secondLogs);
    } else if (dateString === '2019-12-13') {
      return of(this.thirdLogs);
    }
  }
}
```

**date.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DateService {

  firstDate = new Date('2019-12-17');
  secondDate = new Date('2019-12-16');
  thirdDate = null;
  fourthDate = null;
  fifthDate = new Date('2019-12-13');

  getDates(): Observable<Date[]> {
    return of([
      this.firstDate,
      this.secondDate,
      this.thirdDate,
      this.fourthDate,
      this.fifthDate
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not subscribe inside of a `map` function. Try to use `switchMap` and switch to an Observable that combines the results into a new Observable like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dailyLogs$ = this.dateService.getDates()
    .pipe(
      map(values => values.filter(value => !!value)), // User filter to get only truthy dates
      switchMap(dates => combineLatest( // switch to a combined observable of all 'findLogsByDate' calls and map each to the desired output
        dates.map(date => this.logService.findLogsByDate(date) 
          .pipe( 
            map(logList => ({logs: logList, date}))
          )
        )
      ))
    );
}
```

Here a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byyey4).

Comment: But this returns an object of type `Observable<string[][]>`. How can I change this to an object of type `Observable<{logs: string[], date: Date}[]>`?

Comment: I'll add it to my example.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I also added a working Stackblitz with the example code you provided and the adjustments I made.